# Add border to stacked bar chart in plotly R

Tags: r, graph, border, plotly

I am using the following code in R with the `plotly` package to make a grayscale stacked bar graph.

```
hplot1 = plot_ly(big, x=~Month, y=~Cyanophyta, type='bar', name='Cyanophyta', color=I("grey95")) %>%
       add_trace(y=~Chlorophyta, name='Chlorophyta', color=I("grey85")) %>%
       add_trace(y=~Bacillariophyta, name='Bacillariophyta', color=I("grey75")) %>%
       add_trace(y=~Dinophyta, name='Dinophyta', color=I("grey55")) %>%
       add_trace(y=~Cryptophyta, name='Cryptophyta', color=I("grey40")) %>%
       add_trace(y=~Other, name='Other', color=I("grey5")) %>%
       layout(title="2013 Phytoplankton Community", yaxis=list(title='Percent Abundance'), barmode='stack')
```

I am not sure if it is possible to add a border to each individual variable, (i. e. 1 around cyanophyta, 1 around chlorophyta etc.) Can this be done?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Borders can be add to stacked bar charts just like to [regular bar charts](https://plot.ly/r/bar-charts/#bar-chart-with-direct-labels) by adding

```
marker = list(line = list(width = 5,
                          color = 'rgb(0, 0, 0)'))
```

to `add_trace`.

Note: [`color`](https://plot.ly/r/reference/#box-marker-line-color) is mandatory here, the line will otherwise be invisible.

```
library(plotly)

Animals <- c("giraffes", "orangutans", "monkeys")
SF_Zoo <- c(20, 14, 23)
LA_Zoo <- c(12, 18, 29)
data <- data.frame(Animals, SF_Zoo, LA_Zoo)

marker_style <- list(line = list(width = 5,
                                 color = 'rgb(0, 0, 0)'));

p <- plot_ly(data, type = 'bar') %>%
  add_trace(x = ~Animals, y = ~SF_Zoo, name = 'SF Zoo', 
            marker = marker_style) %>%
  add_trace(x = ~Animals, y = ~LA_Zoo, name = 'LA Zoo', 
            marker = marker_style) %>%
  layout(barmode = 'stack')

p
```

[image]